# jQuery - How do you store and access an object within another object

Tags: jquery, object, attributes

I am trying to store an object as an attribute in another object but can't seem to access it.
Is it possible?

```
<script language="javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    //create a TestObject
    function TestObject() {

      this.testProperty = "green";
    }

    //and an instance of it
    var testObject = new TestObject();

    //attach this instance to the div as a property
    //if it could be attached another way perhaps that's the answer??
    $('#test').attr("obj", testObject);

    alert(testObject.testProperty);//works - obviously
    alert($('#test').attr("obj").testProperty); //does not work

    var o = $('#test').attr("obj");
    alert(o.testProperty); //does not work

  });

</script>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="test">Here is a test div</div>
</form>

</body>
```

Answer: The guys below had it right

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//create a TestObject
function TestObject() {
  this.testProperty = "green";
}

//and an instance of it
var testObject = new TestObject();

//attach this instance to the div as a property
var test;
test = $('#test');
jQuery.data(test, "obj", testObject);

alert(testObject.testProperty); //works - obviously
alert(jQuery.data(test, "obj").testProperty); //works!!


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data() instead of attr() ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using the jQuery `attr` function stores the variable as an attribute on the element. If you want to store something a bit more complicated than a string, use `.data`

Answer (score 1):

attribute is intended to store text, not javascript object, using jquery you can use [.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) instead