# jQuery - Accessing object properties from within another object that was passed to an event

Tags: jquery, object, properties, events

[In an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355550/jquery-how-do-you-store-and-access-an-object-within-another-object) I worked out how to store an `object` as `properties`.
Now I am trying to access those `properties` when the `object` is passed through an event but can't get it to work:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //create a TestObject
    function TestObject() {
      this.testProperty = "green";
    }

    //and an instance of it
    var testObject = new TestObject();

    //attach this instance to the div as a property
    var test;
    test = $('#test');//the div
    jQuery.data(test, "obj", testObject);

    //prove it worked and the TestObject is assigned
    alert(jQuery.data(test, "obj").testProperty);//works

    $('#test').click(TestClick);
    //test.click(TestClick); doesn't work either

    function TestClick() {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));//displays "test" - works
        alert(jQuery.data($(this), "obj").testProperty);
        //testProperty is null or not an object??
        //clearly TestObject is no longer attached to the div, why?
        //Or have I attached it the wrong way?    
        //alert(jQuery.data(this, "obj").testProperty); doesn't work either
    };
});
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="test">Here is a test div</div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you, attach it to the element, not as a reference to the element which seems to change slightly (this is a different `.data()` call, [see here for info](http://api.jquery.com/data/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function TestObject() {
    this.testProperty = "green";
  }

  var testObject = new TestObject();
  var test = $('#test').data("obj", testObject);

  alert(test.data("obj").testProperty);

  $('#test').click(TestClick);
  function TestClick() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    alert($(this).data("obj").testProperty);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//clearly TestObject is no longer attached to the div, why?
```

Because `this` returns your function context at this line `alert(jQuery.data($(this), "obj").testProperty);` you should use `alert(jQuery.data($("#test"), "obj").testProperty);` instead.

Comment: That won't work either, in `jQuery.data()` you're storing a reference to the DOM element, which still isn't the same...in normal circumstances, you shouldn't use `jQuery.Data()`, but `.data()` instead.